# Incorrect result for std::is_trivially_constructible<T, T&>::value when T declared T::T(T&)

Tags: c++, type-traits

This is a little problem that I get confused with. I don't know how to describe it, so just see the codes below:

```
struct B {
  B() {}
  B(B&) {
    std::cout << "not trivial\n";
  }
};

int main() {
  B b1;
  B b2(b1);
  std::cout << std::is_trivially_constructible<B,  B&>::value << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
not trivial
1
```

I'm using VS11.

**EDIT:**

I just tested the example in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible. Some of the output is incorrect.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
 
class Foo {
    int v1;
    double v2;
 public:
    Foo(int n) : v1(n), v2() {}
    Foo(int n, double f) : v1(n), v2(f) {}
};
int main() {
    std::cout << "Foo is ...\n" << std::boolalpha
              << "\tTrivially-constructible from const Foo&? "
              << std::is_trivially_constructible<Foo, const Foo&>::value << '\n'
              << "\tTrivially-constructible from int? "
              << std::is_trivially_constructible<Foo, int>::value << '\n'
              << "\tConstructible from int? "
              << std::is_constructible<Foo, int>::value << '\n'
}
```

The output is:

```
Foo is ...
        Trivially-constructible from const Foo&? true
        Trivially-constructible from int? true//Trivially-constructible from int? false
        Constructible from int? true
```

Comment: After reading and re-reading what the standard has to say about this a few times (and deleting my first answer twice over), I believe I've finally found the cause for this confusion. See my answer.

Comment: After a comment by @SebastianRedl I've updated my answer **again** (sigh)..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**FINAL UPDATE**

After a very insightful comment by @SebastianRedl I realized that the intention of the standard is to refer to the entire construction of the object, not just the operations inside the constructor. This would mean that there is, indeed, a bug in Visual C++. However, it is still my view that the wording of the standard is not sufficiently clear, so I'll leave the rest of my answer unchanged for posterity.

To clarify: The behaviour mentioned by the OP is actually a bug, and in light of this, most of what I say below this update is wrong.

**End Update**

This is actually not a compiler bug, but rather a strange quirk of the standard, so your confusion is understandable.

According to the C++11 standard, the following is the condition for `is_trivially_constructible::value` to be `true`.

§20.9

> `is_constructible<T,Args...>::value` is true and the variable definition for `is_constructible`, as defined below, is known to call no operation that is not trivial

So, `is_trivially_constructible` is true as long as the given type is constructible with the given arguments and it does not call any non-trivial operations. Your example includes only one such constructor, a copy constructor. In fact, by the definition of "non-trivial operation" (essentially a non-trivial operator or constructor), this does hold for your type. So returning `true` is correct.

However, there is one very strange point! The C+11 standard says the following about copy constructors:

§12.8.12  (emphasis mine)

> A **copy/move constructor** for class X is trivial if it is **not user-provided** and if
>
> - class X has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1), and
> - the constructor selected to copy/move each direct base class subobject is trivial, and
> - for each non-static data member of X that is of class type (or array thereof), the constructor selected to copy/move that member is trivial;
>
>   otherwise the copy/move constructor is non-trivial.

Since you do provide a user-defined copy constructor your class is not trivially copy constructible. The copy constructor you've given is not trivial. Still, the non-trivial copy constructor *does* fulfil the necessary criteria for `is_trivially_constructible` to return `true` given an argument which matches your copy constructor.

In my mind, this seems to be more of a "bug" in the standard. `is_trivially_constructible` returns whether the type is trivially constructible given certain arguments. This does not seem to guarantee that the constructor itself is deemed trivial!

**Update:**

After trying to devise a test to show this following case, I did find a bug in VC11. The logic described by the standard means that, if `B` is used as a sub-object (member or base) of another type, any constructor of that type which invokes the copy constructor of `B` should be deemed **non-trivial** by `std::is_trivially_constructible`. This is not the case in VC11.

**Example Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct B 
{
  B() {}
  B(B&) {
    std::cout << "not trivial\n";
  }
};

struct A : B
{
  A(B& B) : b(B){}
    B b;
};

int main() 
{
  std::cout << std::is_trivially_constructible<B,  B&>::value << '\n'; // Should print 1
  std::cout << std::is_trivially_constructible<A,  B&>::value << '\n'; // Should print 0
  getchar();
  return 0;
```

}

Comment: @arne Thank you. :) I put a lot of effort into it.

Comment: I don't know what you mean "non-trivial operation" (essentially a non-trivial operator or constructor)" , but even if I call a virtual function inside that copy ctor, the result is still 1, and see my EDIT, the output is different from the one that given by http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible

Comment: @Frahm The definition of what makes an operator (such as assignment) or constructor non-trivial is spread all over the standard. However, calling a virtual function does *not* make your constructor non-trivial. Only calling other functions which are deemed non-trivial will do this. So, unless you call a non-trivial assignment operator, or you specify a non-trivial constructor in your initializer list, your constructor is trivial.

Comment: so, what' is the definition of "non-trivial assignment operator, or you specify a non-trivial constructor"? it seems like a recursion definition.

Comment: @Frahm It is recursive, and the only way a constructor can be non-trivial is if 1) the initialization list includes a non-trivial copy constructor. 2) A member or base is initialized using a non-trivial default-constructor. 3) The body of the constructor calls a non-trivial assignment operator.

Any assignment operator or copy/move/default constructor is non-trivial if it is user-provided. So, there's no error in the output you've provided. However, I have found a closely related bug in VC11! See my update.

Comment: I don't understand the first part of your answer. Why do you claim that the construction as defined by 20.9.4.3p6 does not use any non-trivial operations? It uses the non-trivial copy constructor.

Comment: @SebastianRedl That's a very good point. I interpreted it as that the constructor called does not use any non-trivial operations. But if you instead interpret it as the construction as a whole, then yes, it uses non-trivial operations (the copy-constructor itself). Either way, the wording in the standard is rather fuzzy and opens up for different interpretations or easy misunderstandings.

How about I edit my answer to contain a note about this at the top?

Comment: @SebastianRedl After re-reading the part about `is_constructible`, it seems clear that, in fact, this should be considered non-trivial. I'll update add a note to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible:

The "constructor expression does not call any operation that is not trivial". and that is the case when you write

```
B(B&);
```

nothing fancy going on there, you just pass in a reference.

Comment: trivial means don't be declared, so I think the output is incorrect.

Comment: As I understand said line it just means that the statement with the constructor expression, i.e. the statement calling the constructor, doesn't need to call any other, non-trivial operations like computations that cannot be done at compile time or function calls.

Comment: I think the operation " std::cout << "not trivial\n"; " cannot be done at compile time.