# What types are trivially constructible?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, type-traits

I know, that many types (e.g. POD types) are trivially default-constructible. But what types are [trivially constructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible) from an argument list other than the empty argument list? For example what types are trivially constructible from `int`? I can't think of any.

The following types are not trivially constructible from `int` in C++17 ([live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aTxxq7)):

```
#include <type_traits>

struct X { int x; };
struct Y { Y(int) {} };
struct Z { Z(int) = delete; };

static_assert(std::is_trivially_constructible<X, int>::value == false);
static_assert(std::is_trivially_constructible<Y, int>::value == false);
static_assert(std::is_trivially_constructible<Z, int>::value == false);
```

Comment: According to the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232547/incorrect-result-for-stdis-trivially-constructiblet-tvalue-when-t-declar anytime a user-supplied constructor, copy constructor, or move constructor is used the construction is non trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Trivially constructible from `Args...`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible) is defined as construction from values of the given types that does only do operations considered "trivial". In particular the syntax `T obj(std::declval<Args>()...)` has to call only "trivial" operations.

Up until C++17 the only trivial construction operations possible are default construction, copy construction, and move construction. So if a set of parameters invokes any other constructor or does any other operation as part of doing that construction, such a call cannot be trivial. Therefore in C++17 `std::is_trivially_constructible_v<T, int>` can only be true with `T` = `int` (`int` is trivially copyable from itself).

From C++20 on, which implements [P0960](https://wg21.link/p0960) "Allow initializing aggregates from a parenthesized list of values" `std::is_trivially_constructible_v<X, int>` is true. See [live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nEW58a). This is because the syntax `X obj(std::declval<int>())` calls only trivial operations, which satisfies the requirement of the type trait.

Comment: As of today, Clang 12.0.1 (or the trunk branch) doesn't seem to have implemented this yet. This is appears to be a bug because Clang does consider X to be trivial (std::is_trivial holds for X), which shouldn't be possible if X is not considered to be trivially default constructible.

Comment: Clang 12.0.1 considers `X` to be trivially default-constructible and trivial. I see no contradiction. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xcj4nh6EY).

Comment: You're right, the last sentence of my previous comment is incorrect. For some reason I did the testing of the trivially default constructible trait wrong. However, `static_assert(std::is_trivially_constructible_v<X, int>);` still fails with Clang 12.0.1/trunk while it succeeds with GCC 11.2/trunk when compiling with `-std=c++20`.

Comment: Although I'm not sure about the ramifications of P0960, it might just be that GCC is at fault here. When adding another data member to X (and an int type to the  `is_trivially_constructible` type trait accordingly), GCC no longer succeeds to compile with `-std=c++20`.

Comment: Clang does not currently implement [P0960](https://wg21.link/p0960), see on the [compiler support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) page. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TfecWf9ET). Regarding the next observation (two member variables) I think, that GCC has a bug. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jrrvj9EGz).

Comment: Give `X::x` a default argument, say `3`, then in your live demo `std::is_trivially_constructible<X>::value` is suddenly `false`. Is this correct?

Comment: It's a good [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73348522/which-operation-is-not-trivial-here).

Answer (score 0):

Trivially constructible from is defined as construction from values of the given types that does not do any operation not considered "trivial" (see paragraph 2 [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible)). `int` is a trivially copyable type, so `int` is trivially copyable from itself. Therefore, `std::is_trivially_constructible_v<int, int>` is true.

The only trivial operations possible are default construction, copy construction, and move construction. So if a set of parameters invokes any other constructor or does any other operation as part of doing that construction, such a call cannot be trivial.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could elaborate on why the first one isn't trivial since there are no user-supplied constructors at all?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah: You can't get to question its triviality because `X` is *not constructible* from an `int`. Not until C++20 allows aggregate initialization to work through parentheses. And it can't be "trivially constructible" if it's not "constructible".

Comment: @NicolBolas indeed, OP's code [correctly detect triviality with `X` using C++20](https://godbolt.org/z/4bnn97)

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot: I'm honestly unsure if that is "correct". The question becomes whether aggregate initialization is a trivial operation. The standard says "is known to call no operation that is not trivial." And yes, the specific copy construction into the first member will definitely be a trivial operation. But is aggregate initialization *itself* a "trivial operation"? Or does it not count as an "operation" that gets "called"?

Comment: @Dr.Gut: "*I would consider aggregate initialization itself a trivial operation.*" You can argue that it's true, but that doesn't make it true as far as the standard is concerned. It does explicitly not say that aggregate initialization is a trivial operation if its component operations are trivial. So all you can say is that maybe it *should* be true, not that it *is true*.