# Which operation is not trivial here?

Tags: c++, type-traits

Compilers agree, that the below `X` and `Y` are default-constructible, but not trivially ([demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Wf3vqaac6)).

```
#include <type_traits>

struct X { int x {}; };
struct Y { int y = 0; };

static_assert(std::is_default_constructible_v<X>);
static_assert(std::is_default_constructible_v<Y>);
static_assert(!std::is_trivially_default_constructible_v<X>);
static_assert(!std::is_trivially_default_constructible_v<Y>);
```

Why are they not trivial? According to cppreference.com (see [`is_trivially_constructible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible)) a non-trivial operation must have been called during default-construction. Which one is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Trivial_default_constructor says:

> The default constructor for class T is trivial (i.e. performs no action) if all of the following is true:
>
> - ...
> - T has no non-static members with default initializers. <sub>(since C++11)</sub>
> - ...